# Gamma to Beta: Successes and Failure Proportions?

Tags: gamma-distribution, beta-distribution, reliability

I have a question after reading this article on the [relation between Gamma and Beta distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related) and this article on the [intuitive understanding of the Beta Distribution](http://varianceexplained.org/statistics/beta_distribution_and_baseball/).

#### Question

As the Gamma Distribution is used to predict wait time until the `kth` future event, and the Beta Distribution is "representing a probability distribution of *probabilities,*" is the following accurate?

$$X \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\theta) \text{ models time to successes and } Y \sim \Gamma(\beta,\theta) \text{ models time to failures}$$ then 
$$ \frac{X}{X+Y} \sim Beta(\alpha,\beta) \text{ models proportion of successes to the sum of successes and failures}$$

And this being one reason why the Beta distribution could be used to model mechanical system reliability values.

Please correct me where I am missing information!

Comment: In order to evaluate the accuracy of your statement in Q1, you will need to explain how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are related to $k.$

Comment: I'm uncertain how to address that. Perhaps the best way is that k and theta are equal, but I don't know if that is a valid approach.

Comment: That's how it works for Poisson processes--but not for other processes.  One of the most useful things to know is that the sum of $n$ independent $\Gamma(\alpha)$ variables has a $\Gamma(n\alpha)$ distribution.  With that in mind, it's possible to make (some) intuitive sense of Gamma distributions for any rational $\alpha.$